# What are the best font-paring and complimentary accent color for a brand that uses Old English font and dark blue (#001d3b)?

Tags: color, website-design, font-recommendation, web-fonts, font-pairing

I have a project developing a web app for a school which it's brand and identity using `Old English MT` font and color `#001d3b` (dark blue in the image).

The problem I'm having and currently bugs me is, what is the best suited complimentary font (free/open-source) and accent color for these? Or do I have to ditch the old English font and try modern fonts as alternative? I have tried experimenting with `#F44336` (red orange) along with the font which I currently use is `Open sans` + `Roboto`. The image below is the sample.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You may want to edit out the admin email address from the image here. Personally, I’d try with a serif font, though that may not work too well either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already has accent colors at your logo: red, gold and electric blue.

Actually, the logo not only goes unnoticed but the addition of the orange you have chosen ends up eating it completely. I don't think you need to add the orange, the color is also a composition element and in your case another problem to deal with.

The colors choice is something very personal and subjective, but adjusting to the practicality of the design, I would choose the gold to enhance the logo.

For typography I would choose some of the characteristics of the English Gothic but clean. This Gothic is very condensed, I think a condensed sans serif fits perfectly. Normal and bold for the button. I used the first condensed sans serif I found, Myriad Pro Condensed. I think [Roboto Condensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed) could be ok, try it.

Perhaps it would not saturate the design using white in secondary texts, the gray text creates a hierarchy, the same you use at the menu unselected items.

[image: GOld]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice.  Wow, gold looks cooler than I thought it was.

Comment: @gil and enhances the logo, I think your page needs it ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks for your time and help. Appreciate it.